# C# OpenFileDialog importing variable

Tags: c#

Still new to C#, snipping some code around to write a simple application and learning while doing.

I have an xml file that needs to be ingested and set as a variable so I can have it just insert words from that text file into different text fields.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Displays an OpenFileDialog so the user can select a datafeed.  
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "Datafeed File|*.dfx5";
    openFileDialog1.Title = "Select a dfx5";

    // Show the Dialog.  
    // If the user clicked OK in the dialog and  
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // Assign the file as a variable.  
    }
}
```

How would I make that file a variable so that I can read from it?

Thank you in advanced.  Google-ing didn't return anything helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would I make that file a variable so that I can read from it?

Well, the file *name* that was selected is a property of the [`OpenFileDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx) object:

```
    string fileName;
    // Show the Dialog.  
    // If the user clicked OK in the dialog and  
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // Assign the file as a variable.  
        fileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
    }
```

What you *do* with that file name at that point is up to you.

Comment: I actually used your example BUT I am getting a strange result.  If I do a textBox1.text = FileName; to display contents of the file all I am getting is the directory of the file.  Does that seem right?

Comment: Do you mean literally just the directory (not including the file name) of the complete path of the file? As I said - all you get is the _name_ of the file (including the full path). If you want to show the _contents_ you have to do more work.

Comment: Ok, then yeah I’ve got more work to do.  I need the contents of that file brought in so I can parse it out to different text fields and have it update the file.

Comment: @Nathan, take a look at Danielle's answer. That code not only will read the content of the file, but it will also allow you to easily manipulate the XML data by using that handy `XDocument` instance called `_xmlPayload`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store the **Filename** in a variable, the other answers are what you are looking for.

To me it sounds like you need to actually read the content of the file.
If that's what you want, the following snippet (provided by [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-read-text-from-a-file)) should do:

```
try
{   // Open the text file using a stream reader.
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName))
    {
        // Read the stream to a string, and write the string to the console.
        String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

This way `line` will contain the XML data you need. How you proceed from there is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

If the file is pure XML, then I'd be inclined to do something like this:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

private XDocument _xmlPayload;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Displays an OpenFileDialog so the user can select a datafeed.  
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "Datafeed File|*.dfx5";
    openFileDialog1.Title = "Select a dfx5";

    // Show the Dialog.  
    // If the user clicked OK in the dialog and  
    var dialogResult = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    if (dialogResult == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        //Get file path from dialog
        var filePath = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        //load xml
        using(var stream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
        {
            _xmlPayload = XDocument.Load(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

Then it's up to you how you work with the XML.

Answer (score 0):

openFileDialog1.FileName should have the returned filename from the dialog.  if multiselect is enabled I think its openFileDialog1.FileNames